# Error de Hibernate: Unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, java-ee

La query es la siguiente:

```
 public Persona serachUser(String user,String password){

    sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    s = sf.openSession();
    t = s.beginTransaction();

    Query login = s.createQuery("select Login l where l.usuario ="+user+" and   l.password ="+password);
    Login l = (Login) login.uniqueResult();
    Persona p = new Persona(l.getPersona().getNombre(), l.getPersona().getApellido(),l.getPersona().getDireccion(),l.getPersona().getEmpleo(),l.getPersona().getDescripcion());

    t.commit();
    s.close();
    sf.close();

    return p;

}
```

Al parecer, cuando se reemplazan los parámetros **user** y **password** con dos string, cuando se manda la Query, no se manda con las comillas necesarias para que SQL las interprete como String, me tira el siguiente error:

> Unknown column 'santiago' in 'where clause'

*En este caso, habia reemplazado al parametro user con el nombre santiago

Comment: Por favor comparte tu objeto `Login`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba poniendo comillas simples debería funcionar.

```
Query login = s.createQuery("select Login l where l.usuario = '"+user+"' and   l.password = '"+password+"'");
```

Comment: Esto aunque funciona no es lo mas adecuado, si no fuera por el método createQuery el código seria susceptible de inyección sql. Lo mejor es así:`Query queryLogin= s.createQuery("FROM Login l WHERE l.usuario=:user AND l.password=:pass");
queryLogin.setParameter("user", getUsername());
queryLogin.setParameter("pass", getPassword());
Login login =(Login) queryLogin.uniqueResult();` Acuérdense que es HQL y no SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Para que no te suceda deberías concaternarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
Query login = s.createQuery("select Login l where l.usuario = '"+user+"' and   l.password ='"+password+"'" );
```

Viendo el con detenimiento también te esta faltando el From.

La estructura del Select es
    Select campos1, campo2, ... from tabla where condiciciones...

Espero te sea útil